# FluentValidation Testing Not Handling Expected Nulls

Tags: unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I'm using the great FluentValidation library and have run into an issue in Unit Testing a validator. I have following the example on this wiki page as closely as possible (but I'm using xUnit) https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/g.-Testing

The test which uses the **ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor** extension method.

I am getting a **NullReferenceException** with the test failing. But that is exactly what I am testing for - a null ref for a required field.

Here's is my code:

**Validator:**

```
public class ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ChangeEmailRequestInputModel>
{
    public ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.NewEmail)
            .NotEmpty(); 

        RuleFor(m => m.NewEmail.Trim())
            .EmailAddress()
            .When(m => m.NewEmail != null)
            .WithMessage(ValidationConstants.SymbolIsNotAValidEmailAddress, x => x.NewEmail)
            .WithName("NewEmail"); 

        RuleFor(m => m.NewEmailConfirm.Trim())
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Continue)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Confirm New Email field cannot be empty.")
            .Equal(m => m.NewEmail.Trim()).WithMessage("Confirm New Email field must be equal to the New Email.");
    }
}
```

**The Test:**

```
public class ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidatorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Errors_Where_NewEmail_Is_Null()
    {
        var val = new ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidator();

        val.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(v => v.NewEmail, null as string);            
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? I must have something wrong, but it looks so similar to the example that I am baffled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three rules set up:

1. NewEmail can not be null
2. If NewEmail is not null, trim it and ensure it's a valid email address
3. Trim NewEmailConfirm, ensure it's not empty, compare it against a trimmed NewEmail and make sure it matches.

It's the third rule that's causing issues. The way FluentValidation works under the hood means that the first expression to be evaluated is the expression passed into `RuleFor`, unless you use `When` or `Unless`, both of which backtrack through the rules and apply the predicate or reverse predicate passed into those conditional methods.

So in essence, your validator fires up, it makes its way through 2 of the 3 rules and then starts evaluating the third rule. Your test fixture did not set up a value for NewEmailConfirm, so it starts evaluating the expression chain and hits the first expression, which is `m => m.NewEmailConfirm.Trim()`, this will then blow up.

What you can do to prevent this is the following:

```
[Fact]
public void Errors_Where_NewEmail_Is_Null()
{
    var sut = new ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidator();
    sut.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(v => v.NewEmail, new ChangeEmailRequestInputModel { NewEmail = null, NewEmailConfirm = "demo.email@example.com" });
}
```

This will instantiate your class-under-validation with the right bits to not blow up on that first expression. The problem you're going to face now is that at some point you're going to hit `.Equal(m => m.NewEmail.Trim())`. Your fixture explicitly sets this to `null` in order to test rule 2, so rule 3 still needs to be restructured.

I would suggest the following:

```
public ChangeEmailRequestInputModelValidator(){

    RuleFor(m => m.NewEmail)
        .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Email is a required field.")
        .EmailAddress()
        .WithMessage(
            ValidationConstants.SymbolIsNotAValidEmailAddress, x => x.NewEmail)
        .WithName("NewEmail");

    RuleFor(m => m.NewEmailConfirm)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Confirm New Email field cannot be empty.");

    RuleFor(m => m)
        .Must(HaveMatchingEmailAndConfirmEmail)
        .WithMessage("Confirm New Email field must be equal to the New Email.");
}

private bool HaveMatchingEmailAndConfirmEmail(ChangeEmailRequestInputModel model)
{
    return model.NewEmail?.Trim() == model.NewEmailConfirm?.Trim();
}
```

The above still managed to validate both your properties, independently of each other. It then just checks both properties against each other, making use of the null-coalescing operator to get around explicit null-checking.

Comment: Thanks. That makes complete sense. I knew the problem was with my code. Just couldn't see it.

Comment: Sorry to revisit this, but shouldn't the When condition protect the code from blowing up when the value is null. I expected that Trim would not be called as the When would prevent execution of the code.

Comment: You are right, can you un-accept my answer and I'll update it with the *actual* reason it's blowing up?

Comment: @onefootswill I've just updated the answer, I hope this'll help you out some :)

Comment: Looks good. I'll have a close look tonight. As you can guess, the problem I was having is that sometimes emails were sent to the server with a space on the end. Obviously a copy and paste job. The EmailAddress validator was failing. But I did not want to make users try and work out that they have a space. I just wanted to "deal with it". It's just a space. That's why I was doing the trimming. Apart from trimming at the client, my only other option was to add a custom action filter which runs before the validation action filter to trim emails. Not ideal. Or trim them in the Validator?

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The only thing I have to do is some string trimming at some point. The HaveMatchingEmailAndConfirmEmail method meets the equality aspect, but if a user submits a trailing space, the EmailAddress rule fails. And I don't want an accidental trailing space to fail validation. But I can take it from here. I wonder is there's some kind of decorator I can use to intercept validation and trim the strings. I will look into that. Thanks again!

Comment: @onefootswill Yeah, normally I'd run all values through a normalisation step prior to validation, but I'm guessing you're validating as part of model binding so it's not quite as straightforward. If I have some time today I'll have a little dig about what can be done there, but no promises :)